# Event in windows mobile

Tags: c#, events, windows-mobile

I'm using an event to notify about the progress of treatment of my application. But when I update a label or progress nothing updated in the same time in deguging the code of update is excuted

```
//update label 
void MUpdate_UpdateNotification(string Message)
{
    lblState.Invoke(UpdateLib.Notification.LabelDelegate, new object[] { lblState,  Message });
}
//delegate

public static LabeleAppendHandler LabelDelegate = new LabeleAppendHandler(UpdateLabel);
private static void UpdateLabel(System.Windows.Forms.Label lbl, string msg)
{
    lbl.Text = msg;
}

//how excute event
if (UpdateNotification!=null)
            UpdateNotification(Notification.GetNextStatus());
```

Comment: Sorry, I can't get the second part. The code is not very usefull. What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Windows Mobile runs in a single thread by default so it could be that adding a Application.DoEvents(); could fix your problem.

```
private static void UpdateLabel(System.Windows.Forms.Label lbl, string msg)
{
    lbl.Text = msg;
    Application.DoEvents();
}
```